# react redux dispatch fuction is not triggered

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

> i attach all my required files below for references
>   when i try to call react redux dispatch fuction is not triggered. am new to react redux

**action.js file**

```
import { ITS_USER } from './types';
import {store} from './index'

export  function addPerson(person) {  
    console.log("chek",person);
    console.log("state",store.getState());

    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(adduser(person));

    }
  }

  export  function adduser(person){  
    return {
      type: ITS_USER,
      payload: person
    };
  }
```

**Reducer.js**

```
 import { ITS_USER } from './types';
export default function(state=[], action) {
    console.log("dxasdads",action.type)
    switch (action.type) {


        case ITS_USER:
          return action.payload;

          default:
          return state;

      }    
}
```

**triger function call**

```
   **var person="praveen"
          addPerson(person)**
```

Comment: show the full code of action triggering component. i think you forgot to connect with your component with react-redux connect HOC.

Comment: As im trying to implement without connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect your component with `connect` HOC provided by `react-redux` libary, then you can trigger a dispatch function by dispatching it from `mapStateToProps` passed as a first argument to connect function. Something like this:

```
import YOUR_COMPONENT from './PATH_TO_YOUR_COMPONENT'

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addPerson: (person) => dispatch(addPerson(person)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(YOUR_COMPONENT);
```

And then inside your component, you will get `addPerson` function as your component `props`. You can simply call it by `this.props.addPerson(person)`.

Comment: how to do this without connect ?

Comment: add person is not defined